# How to get index and filename while iterating the list of file path string?

Tags: python, list

Say I have a hypothetical list that lists down some csv files:

```
example_list = ['./Data/File_1.csv',
                './Data/File_2.csv',
                './Data/File_3.csv']
```

And I would like the print to be like:

```
'This is file number 1 for File_1.csv'
'This is file number 2 for File_2.csv'
'This is file number 3 for File_3.csv'
```

Doing a simple `for` loop prints only the first string three times. I thought I would specify the indexes for python to 'recognise' which file I'm referring to, like so:

```
for data in example_list:
    if data[0]:
        print('This is file number 1 for File_1.csv')
    elif data[1]:
        print('This is file number 2 for File_2.csv')
    else:
        print('This is file number 3 for File_3.csv')
```

This too however prints out only the first string. How do I customise what is printed for each index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Job for `enumerate`:

```
for (idx, st) in enumerate(example_list, 1):
    print('This is file number {} for {}'.format(idx, st.split('/')[-1]))
```

- `enumerate(example_list, 1)` enumerates the list with setting starting index as `1`
- `print('This is file number {} for {}'.format(idx, st.split('/')[-1]))` prints in desired format, with `st.split('/')[-1])` getting the last member of the `/` `split`-ted list.

As `/` is the directory separator in POSIX systems, no filename can contain `/`, so `split('/')[-1]` should works the same as `os.path.basename`. But, it's better to use `os.path.basename` BTW.

**Example:**

```
In [46]: example_list = ['./Data/File_1.csv',
                './Data/File_2.csv',
                './Data/File_3.csv']

In [47]: for (idx, st) in enumerate(example_list, 1):
    print('This is file number {} for {}'.format(idx, st.split('/')[-1]))
   ....:     
This is file number 1 for File_1.csv
This is file number 2 for File_2.csv
This is file number 3 for File_3.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

`enumerate` your list, print a formatted string. You can get the base-name of a file with `os.path.basename`.

```
>>> from os.path import basename
>>> example_list = ['./Data/File_1.csv',
...                 './Data/File_2.csv',
...                 './Data/File_3.csv']
>>> 
>>> for i, fname in enumerate(example_list, 1):
...     print('This is file number {} for file {}'.format(i, basename(fname)))
... 
This is file number 1 for file File_1.csv
This is file number 2 for file File_2.csv
This is file number 3 for file File_3.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) *(to get indices while iterating)* with [**`os.path.basename`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) *(to get filename from the filepath)* to achieve this. Here's a *list comprehension* expression as an example:

```
>>> import os
>>> example_list = [
    './Data/File_1.csv',
    './Data/File_2.csv',
    './Data/File_3.csv']

>>> ['This is file number {} for {}'.format(i, os.path.basename(name)) for i, name in enumerate(example_list)]
['This is file number 0 for File_1.csv', 'This is file number 1 for File_2.csv', 'This is file number 2 for File_3.csv']
```